# Migrate to SharePoint 2010 and upgrade xml files

Tags: upgrade

I started to migrate a SharePoint 2007 to a SharePoint 2010. I make a database-attachment upgrade and run the Upgrade-SPContentDatabase-Identity test_WSS_content_vslbmoss16 in a SharePoint 2010 Management Shell. In my log file I get this warning:

[powershell] [SPContentDatabaseSequence] [WARNING] [08-02-2011 16:54:10]: File [Features\HLUPaperlight2Archivelist\Archive\DispForm.aspx] is referenced [256] times in the database [test_WSS_content_vslbmoss16], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file.
[powershell] [SPContentDatabaseSequence] [WARNING] [08-02-2011 16:54:10]: One or more setup files are referenced in the database [test_WSS_content_vslbmoss16], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

To correct the error I make a STS1upgrade.xml file under 14-hive/config/upgrade

```
 <? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
 <Config xmlns="urn:Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade">
 <WebTemplate>
 <Files>
 <File
 FromPath = "Features\HLUPaperlight2Archivelist\Archive\DispForm.aspx"
 ToPath = "FEATURES\LuPaDoc.Archivelist\Archive\DispForm.aspx">
 </File>
 </Files>
 </WebTemplate>
 </Config>
```

I restart IIS by doing an iisreset. Restore my database, so it gets my old SharePoint 2007 database and runs an Upgrade SPContentDatabase-Identity test_WSS_content_vslbmoss16. But still get the same error. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try either installing the feature, if you have it, or just copying the missing file directly. After you install the missing file use Test-SPContentDatabaseWindows to verify that the warning has gone away, and see if anything else is missing.

As a general point, rather than go straight to Upgrade-SPContentDatabase, a good idea is to run Test-SPContentDatabase first to identify problems before attempting the actual database upgrade.